# Schedule cronjob to remove files modified before X days

Tags: cron, aix

I want to create and schedule cronjob to remove files modified before x days

I have taken following steps for that

Created Shell script (Named: Script.sh) as bellow

```
#!/bin/sh

15 2 * * 2-6  find  /usr/sch/cbm/files/newui/log -type f -mtime +2 exec rm {} \;
```

I have put this file in "/var/spool/cron/crontabs" and usr/bin folder because i wasn't sure where to place exactly.

When i check with Crontab -e command get as in bellow image

[image]

But i didn't found any effect on my files. I am not sure is my job scheduled or i required to do anything else still

please guide me

Comment: Create a separate script like `/home/myself/admin_scripts/cleanlogs.sh` and run that script from crontab. In the script you can do any debugging/logging you want.

Comment: Updated shell script file with:  #!/bin/bash
find  /usr/Schneider/cbm/files/newui/log -type f -mtime +2 exec rm {} \;            and created cronjob with: "0,30 * * * * /usr/local/bin/script.sh >> /home/vsp004/Cronlog.txt 2>&1" Get following in log file   "sh: /usr/local/bin/script.sh: cannot execute"

Comment: `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

```
crontab <file>
```

where file is what you have above will put the file in the right place and make sure everything is happy for cron to run it.

```
crontab -l
```

will display the list of cron jobs for the currently logged in user.

Note that the file itself does not execute so no need for #!/bin/sh as the first line.  It is just a data file that cron interprets.

```
man 5 crontab
```

and

```
man 1 crontab
```

for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to insert cron job line in cron file of user who executes that job.

1. su - username
2. crontab -e
3. add cron job line
4. save and exit

Example for removing files before x days

> 00 00 * * * find /path/to/folder -mtime +x -exec rm {} \;

or you can do that for some files exist in folder

For example remove files end with .log

> 00 00 * * * find /path/to/folder/*.log -mtime +x -exec rm {} \;